# Divisibility of coefficients of power series

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $f = a_0 + a_1t + a_2t^2 + \cdots$ be a power series with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $p$ be a prime number, and suppose $p$ does not divide all of the coefficients of $f$. That is to say, $p$ does not divide $f$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[[t]]$.

Let $P(X)\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ be a polynomial, such that $p$ does not divide $P(X)$. Could $p$ divide $P(f)$ (in $\mathbb{Z}[[t]]$?

Comment: Easier to answer when both $f$ and $P$ have constant term zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $p=2$, $f=1+2t$, $P=1+x^2$? Or even just $f=1$.

Neither $f$ nor $P$ is divisible by $2$. But
$$
P(f)=1+(1+2t)^2=1+1+4t+4t^2=2+4t+4t^2
$$
is divisible by $2$. So is $P(1)=2$.

Comment: Yes when $f$ is constant in $\mathbb{F}_p[[t]]$ it is trivial $t \mapsto f(t)$ is not injective. But what if $f$ is non-constant ?

Answer (score 1):

- If $g(t) \in \mathbb{F}_p[[t]]^*$ then $\phi : t \mapsto t\, g(t)$ defines a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{F}_p((t))\to \mathbb{F}_p((t))$. And since $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ is a field then $\phi$ is injective $\mathbb{F}_p[[t]]\to \mathbb{F}_p[[t]]$ and $\mathbb{F}_p[t]\to \mathbb{F}_p[[t]]$.
- If $f(t)\in  \mathbb{F}_p[[t]]$ is **non-constant** then $f(t)= f(0)+t\, g(t)$ with $g(t), \phi$ as above. Let $\psi : t \mapsto t+f(0)$ an injective homomorphism $\mathbb{F}_p[t]\to \mathbb{F}_p[t]$ so that $\phi \circ \psi : t \mapsto f(t)$ is an injective homomorphism $\mathbb{F}_p[t]\to \mathbb{F}_p[[t]]$.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is not sufficiently sharply focused. My example is $f(t)=1+pt$, $P(t)=-1+t$, so that $(P\circ f)(t)=pt$.

Comment: Ah, okay, but I suppose the statement would be true if we assume that $f$ has nonconstant coefficients which are not divisible by $p$. In that case, $f\mod p$ would is not a constant in $\mathbb{F}_p[[t]]$, and so the only way it satisfies a nonzero polynomial mod $p$ is if it is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_p$, which it is not, since the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[[t]]$ is just $\mathbb{F}_p$, and $f$ is not a constant in $\mathbb{F}_p[[t]]$.

Comment: My own approach is to restrict to power series with no constant term at all; or to power series whose constant term is in the maximal ideal ($p\Bbb Z_p$ in this case).